# how to get the data in SharedPreference from another class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to get the data stored in shared preference in another class,

```
  public class MyActivity_Settings extends ListActivity {


                //Shared Preference
                SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
                public static final String MYPREFERENCES = "MyUserChoice";
                public ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

//onCreate
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         @Override
            public void finish() {

        String selected = "My string"

                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                prefEditor.putString(MYPREFERENCES, selected);
                prefEditor.apply();
                super.finish();
            }
```

So basically from another class I want to check if MYPREFERENCE has some data and also use that data such that I can further code

I want to do something like this

```
 if (mSharedPreferences.contains(MYPREFERENCES)) {
            String savedItems = mSharedPreferences.getString(MYPREFERENCES, "");
            selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));
```

This is on another activity

```
   MyActivity_Settings mMyActivity_settings = new MyActivity_Settings();

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Obviously this is not working

    if(mMyActivity_settings.mSharedPreferences.contains(mMyActivity_settings.MYPREFERENCES){

Toast.makeText(this, " From MainACTIVITY WE HAVE DATA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


    }

     }
```

Comment: please show the code that you use for int `mSharedPreferences` in `MyActivity_Settings `

Comment: Read more about Android and Context.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh i have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your other class (Activity) you should attach this code in order to take your `SharedPreferences`:

`SharedPreferences sharedPref;
 sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCESKEY , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String selected = sharedPref.getString("MyUserChoice","");`

Also you have not initialized your `SharedPreferences` instance, you should initialize it like this in your current activity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCESKEY , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

if you want to check if your `SharedPreferences` has data you can check the value that the `SharedPreference` with key value `MyUserChoice` has , in order not to be equal with blank `String`. As you see in `sharedPref.getString("MyUserChoice","");` the second parameter is the default value when you have not any data. The proper way to check is this
`if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())`

Comment: Yes I do understand this.currently there are two activities one is mMyActivity_settings & the other is MyActivity. So, I have shared preference set up as per your answer and my code above in mMyActivity now I need to use sharedpreference in MyActivity ,
Your answer works fine when working in the same activity but then I fail to understand how will it work when checking it from another activity.

Comment: Bare in mind that `SharedPreferences` are something global in your APP, they write data to the local storage of your phone so they are available through all your activities or services etc. Maybe you use different key to instantiate `SharedPreferences`. Please see this link : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 2):

In most of the apps, I create `MyApp` that extends `Application` class.
I wrote most of the SharePreference methods in `MyApp` class.

```
public static String getUsername() {
        SharedPreferences mAppPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return mAppPreferences.getString("USERNAME", "");
    }

public static void setUsername(String username) {
        SharedPreferences mAppPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Editor mEditor = mAppPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putString("USERNAME", username);
        mEditor.commit();
    }
```

So, you can get or set data in every Activity easily.
To get data, simply call:

```
MyApp.getUsername();
```

To set data , call :

```
MyApp.setUsername("Your User Name");
```

Hope, this will help for you.

Comment: How do u access / initiate **context**  in .getDefaultSharedPreferences(**context**) ?

Comment: init in your application class 's onCreate() 

public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApp.context = getApplicationContext();

    }

Answer (score 1):

In the other activity you can reget the sharedprefs using:

```
   mSharedPreferences = gettApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And check it there:

```
 mSharedPreferences.contains(KEY);
```

Edit: adding full example for clarity:

1st activity

```
    private final static String MYPREFERENCES = "myapppref";//pref file name
    private final static String MY_PREF_KEY = "timesclicked";//a key for the sharedpref map key->value

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        [do usual stuff layout and so on...]
        //first argument is the preference filename, if not existing it will be created, you can use a lot of different files if you need to
        SharedPreference mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //store a value to this pref file, in this case a key MY_PREF_KEY is a costant, value is what you want to store
        mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(MY_PREF_KEY, value).apply();
    }
```

2nd activity

```
public void checkMyPrefKeyExistance(){
    //get the pref file with the same name as first activity
    SharedPreference mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //check if key exists
    boolean hasKey = mSharedPreferences.contains(KEY);
    //get value for key, or default value, in this case def val is empty string
    mSharedPreferences.getString(MY_PREF_KEY, "");
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: what is SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME here ? How do I initialize it?

Comment: I edited the answer with a full example, should be clearer now